# Error in Hirsch?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology, lebesgue-measure

Consider the following lemma:

[image]

In the fragment:

> Write $\displaystyle X= \bigcup_{1}^{\infty} X_j$ where each $X_j$ is a compact subset of a ball $B$ as above.

why is he allowed to do that? If the $X_j$ were such that they were each **inside** a compact subset of a ball $B$ as above, I would understand. But this way, I don't see how this construction is possible. My question is: How is this construction performed?

Comment: If each $X_j$ is a subset of a ball $B$, is it not inside $B$?

Comment: Yes, but the issue is that they are taken to be compact.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that you had "inside *a compact subset* of a ball $B$"; for some reason I thought you had written just "inside a ball $B$".

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you have a ball $B$ of radius $r$ take a closed ball of radius $\delta < r$ inside $B$ which contains all points of $X$. If there are points of $X$ arbitrarly near the boundary of $B$, take as the original $B$ a ball slightly larger... Am I missing something?

Comment: @Brainstorming, you may still have the problem: Imagine $U$ the unit ball and $X$ the set of points in $U$ with $x_n=0$. But this isn't the point. We just use second countability and local compactness of $\Bbb R^n$ to obtain the $X_j$ in the proof.